# Angular bootstrap shows empty page

Tags: angular, web, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io

in my app , but when i add it to `app.module` it causes the webpage to display empty without any errors

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { TComponent } from './t/t.component'; 
import { PComponent } from './p/p.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    TComponent,
    PComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, 
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any reason or what fix i can do ?

Comment: When you say no errors, do you mean it compiles and runs without errors? Or do you mean no errors in the browser console?

Comment: @saglamcem  it compiles and runs  no errors in terminal and i see empty web page

Comment: Can you share your app.component.html?

Comment: @saglamcem there is no line of code related to that library for now , the pages shows when i remove it from modules

Comment: I know it's a stupid suggest but, Are you installed in your app using `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`? are you download a bootstrap.min.css, put in a folder and add in angular.json tag "script"? BTW What version of Angular are you using?